# One db call when a ManyToManyField relationship is involved

Tags: django, django-models

I wish to implement an endpoint which returns a student's subjects, but only if they are not attending a private school. This is how I plan to do it:

```
class Subject(Model):
    students = model.ManyToManyField()

class Student(Model):
    subjects = model.ManyToManyField()
    school = model.ForeignKey(School)

class School(Model):
    is_private = model.BooleanField()


is_private = Student.objects.select_releated("school").get(student_id).is_private
if is_private:
   raise Http403

return Subject.objects.filter(students__pk=student_id)
```

So I am calling the database twice. Is it possible to do this in django by calling the database once and would it be more efficient to do so? Is there a use case for prefetch_related here?

Another example: given a student's id, how would I get the student's name and the number of subjects they have, with only one call to the db? This would involve two calls to the db:

```
student = Student.objects.get(student_id)
print(student.name)
print(student.subjects.count())
```

Answer (score 2):

A silly way to do this would be:

```
return Subject.objects.filter(students__is_private=False, student__pk=student_id)
```

In case the `Student` has `is_private` set to `True`, it will return an empty queryset.

> Is it possible to do this in django by calling the database once and would it be more efficient to do so? Is there a use case for `prefetch_related` here?

[**`.prefect_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does *not* fetch the the data in the same query, it will make a second query, but that is a good idea: if you would make a `JOIN`, you would retrieve a *lot* of *duplicated data*, which would be inefficient, both for the database, Python/Django and the bandwidth between the two. So in this specific case, using two queries would be better than one. Too bad that Django/Python do not (yet) have an effective implementation of the [*Haxl monad* <sup>[paper]</sup>](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/haxl-icfp14.pdf), which makes batching/stacking queries transparent, and also makes it convenient to make multiple queries concurrently.

As for the latter, you can do this more efficiently with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

student = Student.objects.annotate(nsubjects=Count('subject')).get(pk=student_id)

print(student.name)
print(student.nsubjects)
```

This will simply add an extra column to the result, and thus does *not* introduce duplicated data.